# Highcharts Column Zones

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Highcharts series "zones" are, if I'm understanding [the documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.zones) correctly, supposed to re-color the data point as the value passes into different "zones".

- This works when originally loading the table using either 'line' or 'column' 'chart type'.
- This works when I update the value of a data point of a chart with type 'line'
- This does *not* work when I update the value of a data point of chart type 'column'

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bfb6w1qq/1/

You can try setting the type from 'column' to 'line' to see it work as expected.

My question is - is this a bug or am I missing some kind of configuration setting? I even tried forcing a re-draw, but still no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
$(function () {
$("#higher").on("click", function()
{
    chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.series[0].data[0].update(
        {
            x: 0,
            y: 15
        })
    chart.redraw();
});

$('#container').highcharts({
     chart:
        {
            type: 'column'
        },
    series: [{
        data: [-10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 10, 10, 5, 0, -5],
        zones: [{
            value: 0,
            color: '#f7a35c',
            fillColor: '#f7a35c'
        }, {
            value: 10,
            color: '#7cb5ec',
            fillColor: '#7cb5ec'
        }, {
            color: '#90ed7d',
            fillColor: '#90ed7d'
        }]
    }]
});
```

});

Comment: I don't know the solution, but one observation: I don't think it works correctly when updating the value of a data point of a chart with type 'line'. If you look again, the line colour updates but not the point colour. So I guess it's a general issue, not column specific.

Comment: @sheilak Wow.  I didn't notice that.  You're right.  Next thing I notice is that if you mouse-over the element and then mouse-out, the element turns the correct color.  Maybe there is some way I can simulate what's happening in "mouse-out" to bypass the issue.

Comment: Interesting! Looks like a bug to me. Another option for working around it would be to use removePoint and addPoint, but that won't give the same animation effect of the column moving up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for feedback, Indeed looks like a bug, so I reported that to our developers here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4604

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in current bug-fix branch, apparently.  Woohoo!

https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4604#event-420605840